# Unable to resolve error in Qualtrics Initialization

Tags: android, android-studio, qualtrics

I'm a newbie in Android development.
I'm getting an error when I'm trying to initialize an instance of Qualtrics.
I have created the intercept ID and Creative ID for the Qualtrics survey that I'm using here.
Here's the code for MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Qualtrics.instance().initialize("abc", "ZN_51hH0BfnHQUZF", "SI_d50cthAy2SEFO",this);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Qualtrics.instance().evaluateTargetingLogic(new MyCallBack());
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the error I keep getting in the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.qualtrics_apptest, PID: 6690
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.qualtrics_apptest/com.example.qualtrics_apptest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:113)
        at com.qualtrics.digital.SiteInterceptService.postErrorLog(SiteInterceptService.java:93)
        at com.qualtrics.digital.CrashReporter.logCrash(CrashReporter.java:6)
        at com.qualtrics.digital.Qualtrics.initialize(Qualtrics.java:106)
        at com.qualtrics.digital.Qualtrics.initialize(Qualtrics.java:58)
        at com.example.qualtrics_apptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this error is occurring?